# Persisting a large DataFrame on disk?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, serialization

For my project i need to serialize pandas dataframe. Which is the best way to serialize pandas dataframe. I have a very large dataframe. I am thinking about following formats but each have saome limitaions.

```
Pickle : issues with very large dataframe.
hdf5 : issues with mixed datatypes
csv : ok, but have very large size
```

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the many compression formats supported by pandas `read_csv`/`to_csv` methods:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', compression='gzip')
```

This saves your data as a compressed CSV, which occupies considerably less space (~60%+ compression is possible based on my experience). When loading, you'll need the equivalent;

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', compression='gzip')
```

Other supported formats are `bz2` and `xz`.

Comment: Can you suggest any other format? csv format does not preserve the datatypes of attributes of dataframe

Comment: @AvinashMagar When you load in your data, you can specify a converter so the types are preserved.